Where do I go wrong with this Lagrange multiplier example?
I am having a hard time understanding why the maximum of a function $f$ under a constraint $g(x,y)=0$ always falls such that the contours are parallel. To illustrate, I have cooked up the example:
Maximize $f(x,y) = y-2x$ under the constraint $g(x,y) = y-x^3-2 = 0$
Here, it does not seem to me that the maximum of $f(x,y)$ under $g(x,y)=0$ occurs when the contours are parallel. In fact, we can continue to find larger and larger values of $f(x,y)$ while satisfying $g(x,y)=0$ (see plot). I am sure I am misunderstanding something, but not sure exactly what. Any guidance would be appreciated.


Lagrange multipliers are for finding local maxima and minima.

Constrained extrema are only guaranteed to coincide with stationary points of the Lagrangian if the constraint curve is compact. Here the constraint curve is unbounded.
